Failure to Communicate Between Foxy Docker Image and Drone
I am trying to establish communication between ROS 2 nodes on different devices on a local WiFi network. The first device is a drone running an older version of Ubuntu (18.04) so it is running ROS 2 Foxy. The other device, my PC, has a more recent Ubuntu version (22.04) that does not support Foxy. Therefore, I am running Foxy in a Docker container on that PC (from Docker Desktop). The container is launched with the following command: docker run --net=host -it --rm -v ~/docker-workspaces/custom_foxy_ws:/home/user/ros_ws custom_ros2_foxy_image:latest bash. Notably, the net=host means it is mean to directly use the host PC's network. I am using a custom docker image for this, which simply contains the official osrf/ros:foxy-desktop image followed by run commands to install everything added during the Foxy installation instructions (since some of this didn't come with the base image) and then install the Nano text editor. However, the issue persists even when I use the vanilla osrf/ros:foxy-desktop image or a different foxy image that I downloaded.
ROS 2 nodes run on the drone are not visible or accessible to the nodes in the container or vice versa. For example, they do not appear when using ros2 node list or ros2 topic list and when I run a publisher and subscriber from the ROS 2 tutorials a subscriber on one device cannot pick up topics from the other.
Here are some troubleshooting steps I have tried. When using ros2 multicast send and ros2 multicast receive the container cannot communicate with either the drone or the host PC (the PC that I'm running the container on). However, the drone and the host PC can communicate which each other using this method despite the fact that the host PC runs Humble instead of Foxy. This leads me to think that the trouble is more likely to be in the way Docker's networking interacts with ROS 2 discovery rather than anything regarding the local WiFi network between drone and PC. Multiple container instances can communicate with each other using ros multicast as well.
Despite the fact that I can't receive ros2 multicasts from outside the container, an iperf client set up within the container can communicate with an iperf server on the host PC. (Using iperf -s -u -B 239.0.0.1for server and iperf -c 239.0.0.1 -u -T 32 -t 10 -i 1  for client). The container can ping the drone and the IP of the host PC (which I assume should be the container's IP too). Using hostname -I on one container instance, I got 192.168.65.9, 192.168.65.6, and 172.17.0.1. The 172 address is likely from the bridge network and the others are on the internal Docker subnet. The drone and PC have 192.168.0.196 and 192.168.0.84 addresses on the local WiFi network.
Since there appeared to be a problem with ROS 2 multicasting, I used ip maddr on the drone and PC. Both have access to the 224.0.0.1 multicast address and do not share any other addresses. I haven't configured them with a multicast address beyond this. To my knowledge, the drone and PC are the only devices connected to the router.
I also tried to get around the issue by using FastDDS Discovery Server rather than multicast. This worked between terminals on my host PC but I could not establish communication between the host PC and the container or even between different container instances. I made sure that the container could ping 127.0.0.1 which is used as part of the server address.
Anybody know what to make of this? Thanks in advance.
EDIT: The problem has been resolved. I uninstalled my Docker Desktop setup and installed Docker Engine using apt install. I used remove instructions from here and here to make sure I got rid of enough of the old installation. This also involved deleting and rebuilding the image, although I doubt that the image was the issue since I previously tried multiple Foxy images to see if any could connect. ros2 multicast send and receive now work between container and the PC and drone. Topics published on one installation are also visible on the others.

Could you try and run a simple ros2 topic list on your PC with Humble(?) installed?
It is not advisable, but you can see topics published by e.g. Foxy when using e.g. Humble.
Maybe it's not a docker, but a general network issue.

I did use that command. ros2 topic list run from the PC can view Foxy topics from the drone but not from the Docker container.

Perfect, that means the host-PC gets the messages. Then it's only a question of Host<->Docker setup. Could you run the docker with the following flags: --network=host --ipc=host --pid=host? Also, the rootless-mode is usually advised when running dockers, which you need to disable. See this stackoverflow.com/question
